# Can I add a control rig to a character after animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, motion-capture

I imported mocap animation to a basic rig and i want to clean up the mess. So my question is can I add controls over the basic bone structure after the animation been imported.If yes.please guide me through the process.I have no idea about rigging.

Comment: You should be more specific with your issue, post some screenshots or even blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/